# readyState":0,"status":0,"statusText":"error" while Call api through AjaxCall Realsed Apk android

Tags: android, ajax, cordova

While hitting an API using ajax call l got below error

```
readyState":0,"status":0,"statusText":"error"
```

Ajax call method:

```
var deviceId = FCM_Tocken_localStorage_GET();
//console.log(" Status ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~>  " + deviceId);
//  alert(deviceId);
//debugger
var site = window.localStorage.getItem("site_id");

$.ajax({
    url: baseURL + '/api/saveDeviceId?deviceId='+deviceId,
    type: 'POST',
    success: function(result) {
        console.log("ResponseMessage----------------> " + JSON.stringify(result));
       // alert(JSON.stringify(result));
        if (result.status == "success") {
        } else {
            }
  //      $(".modal").hide();
    },
    error: function(exception) {
     alert(JSON.stringify(exception));
  console.log('Exception:~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~> ' + exception);
 //       $(".modal").hide();
        }

})
```

kindly let me help to overcome this issue

Comment: please check your back-end for error.

Comment: what was the error

Comment: can any one tell me the reason

Answer (score 0):

at last i found answer ,mentioned below:

```
// A new webclient that ignore ssl errors
private class IgnoreSSLErrorWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    // You can call the class anything

@Override
public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) 
{
 handler.proceed(); // When an error occurs, ignore and go on
}
}
 The site has issues with SSL certificate verification. The default WebViewClient stops loading when there is an SSL verification error. This extension will instruct it to disregard the error and proceed.
```

[from this link I found my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57027277/error-while-trying-to-load-a-url-in-webview-android)  that one for webwiew it applicable for Cordova Android app also